# In regex, what happen when we omit the "^" or the "$"?

Tags: regex

I know that the `$` symbol indicates the end of a line or string.

Must it be place in to the regex?

What happens or how does the meaning change when we omit the `$`?

For example:

```
^/abc/\w{1,3}
^/abc/\w{1,3}$
```

What is the difference in the above two lines?

Comment: First regex will also match `/abc/foo-bar-baz` but 2nd will only match `/abc/foo` OR `/abc/123` OR `/abc/9`

Comment: @anubhava why not post that as an answer since it's complete and correct?  :)

Comment: Actually I was crucified once on SO for answering a simple question like this so I started avoiding very simple answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depens on what you want. You are not required to write anything into a regex, even  (empty) is a valid regex to some extent.

The difference in the two patterns is, that the first one **checks if the subject starts with the pattern** while the second one **checks if the whole subject matches the pattern exactly**.

`/abc/hello world` would match the first one, but not the second.

So to say, the scond pattern is a more specific version of the first one.

Answer (score 1):

The first one matches on `/abc/aapje`, the second doesn't because it mandates that the end-of-line must follow after 1 to 3 word characters.

Answer (score 1):

Well the first regex `^/abc/\w{1,3}` will match `/abc/aaa123` where as `^/abc/\w{1,3}$` will not.

The reason for this is that the `$` anchor matches the end of a line.
Likewise the `^` anchor matches the start of a line.

Neither the `^` or `$` anchors are compulsory, in-fact if you wished to match something in the middle of a string you would omit both of them. E.g. `/abc/\w{1,3}` would match the `/abc/def` in the centre of this string `Some text /abc/def more text`.

If you want to see how adding various anchors effects the regex I'd recommend trying [Regex101.com](http://regex101.com/) or [Debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/).

Comment: You should expand on your answer. Tell OP why it will not match.